# Form JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm using a piece of code that filters through an array of JavaScript variables and locates the user depending on the input. What I currently have below is if any of the variables are entered, the user is redirected to index.php, what I want is if item 1 of the array is entered, you're directed to main.html, item 2 is entered and you're directed to index.html etc. Here is the code I already:

```
var variable = ["1", "2", "3"];

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
  if (variable.indexOf(x) == -1) {
    alert("No variable in array entered");
    return false;
  }

  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
  if (variable.indexOf(x) != -1) {
    window.location.href = "index.php";

    return false;
  }    
}
```

Comment: is `myForm` is the name/id of the `<form` tag ? and `value` is the name/id of text box ?

Comment: You didn't say what problem you are experiencing

Comment: Why are you using `var` instead of `let` or `const`?  Why are you redeclaring `x`?  Why are you not using `else' or `else if` in conjunction with `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object with authorized values as keys and files as values:

```
var variable = {
  1: 'index.php', 
  2: 'main.html', 
  3: 'index.html'
};

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
  const file = variable[x];
  if (file)
    window.location.href = file
  else 
    alert("No variable in array entered");
}
```